# ¿Como crear un TextView para letras y cifrado de canciones en Android?

Tags: android

He estado desarrollando un app para incluir un repertorio musical que incluya las letras y el cifrado de las armonías, he intentado de varias maneras, una de ellas usando spans, ya que asi lo había hecho en html, modificando las propiedades ccs,pero en android no ofrece tanta versatilidad con los span y no quisiera usar un WebView si no un TextView ya que quisiera añadirle otras funcionalidades de edición.No he encontrado mucha información al respecto en internet.Aquí le pongo un ejemplo de lo que he hecho.

```
public void setText(){
        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto);
        SpannableStringBuilder textSpan=new SpannableStringBuilder("Este es Cun ejemplo de la Amletra con el cifradoF de la armoníaG de una canción");
        for(int i=0;i<spans.length;i++) {
            textSpan.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(){
                public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
                    super.updateDrawState(tp);
                    tp.baselineShift=(int)tp.ascent();

                    tp.setColor(Color.RED);
                    tp.bgColor=Color.BLUE;
                }
            }, spans[i][0], spans[i][1], Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        textview.setMinLines(100);
        textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textview.setPadding(30, 30, 30, 30);
        textview.setText(textSpan);

    }
```

Quisiera que el cifrado no ocupara espacio en la linea de la letra pero no encuentro forma de hacerlo. Si hay alguna sugerencia la agradezco.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado un ejemplo parecido a lo que queria hacer usando el objeto layout de la clase TextView para calcular la posición del cifrado. Midifico el método onDraw() para que me dibuje el la letra como un texto normal y luego que me calcule la posición de las armonias. 
Aqui le dejo el como quedaría el el método onDraw():

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        TextPaint pincel = getPaint();
        pincel.setColor(Color.RED);

        //Recupero el layout del TextView
        Layout layout = getLayout();

        //Recorro un array de objetos tipo Cifrado que he creado
        for(Cifrado c:cif){
            //Calcula las coordenadas del cifrado según la posición del caracter sobre el que quiero hubicarlo
            double x = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(c.getPos()+1);
            int line = layout.getLineForOffset(c.getPos()+1);
            double y = layout.getLineBaseline(line);
            //Dibuja el cifrado
            canvas.drawText(c.getCifrado(),(int)x,(int)y,pincel);
        }

    }

    private Cifrado[] cif;
```

La clase **Cifrado** es una clase simple con dos campos  pos(posción) de tipo *int* y otro **String** cifrado.

Aqui hay una respuesa que hace algo más complejo pero me sirvió:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905486/how-get-coordinate-of-a-clickablespan-inside-a-textview